# python, How to make an argument accept a combination of arguments?

Tags: python, argparse, args

I did see another post on making python args accept multiple inputs but I don't think that applies to my question here.

I have a script that executes using command line and I made an argument where I could input a model and based on the model, my script will update a file for me that I can use in another program (this is for codeml.ctl file for PAML in case anyone is interested).

I execute the script as:

```
python my_script.py -g=geneA.phy -t=treefile.phy -M="0 1 2 3"
```

But sometimes I may want to rerun just one model so:

```
-M=0
```

Or perhaps I want to rerun two random models

```
-M="0 3"
```

In my python script, I have it setup so based on the model input for my -M flag, I edit lines in the control file.

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Update codeml.ctl file using model names")
    parser.add_argument('-M', '--modeltype', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-g', '--genefile', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--treefile', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

def lines_to_replace(args):
    replace_seq = args.genefile
    replace_treefile = args.treefile
    replace_outfile = args.genefile.split(".phy")[0] + "_OUT"

def model(args):
    for index, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('codeml.ctl', inplace=1)):
        if args.modeltype == '0 1 2 3':
             if index == 30:
                 line = "Model is 0 1 2 3"; print(line)
        if args.modeltype == '0 1 2':
             if index == 30:
                 line = "Model is 0 1 2"; print(line)
```

And I would do this but this is tedious and I cannot figure out a way for my args.modeltype to accept a combination of model inputs. The actual file only takes model inputs with spaces in between and it has to be on one line. It would have to be something like:

```
 if args.modeltype == ???:
      if index == 30:
           line = "Model is" + str(???); print(line)
```

Combinations always confuse me. Would something like *args work for this, but then how would I parse *args? Perhaps using user input and saving that as a variable would work? I've never used that before but I will try it.

---

Edit to be more clear:

I want my model argument to accept arguments from this list of models [0, 1, 2, 3]. I can just type 0, or I could type "0 1" or even "2 3" and the script should execute and update the model line (index == 30) appropriately. However, if I type "9 99" that is wrong because those models don't exist. The suggestions below work where I use nargs="+" and then " ".join(args.model), but this still accepts incorrect input.
Is there a way to input the list of accepted models into my parser.add_argument('model', type='str', nargs='+', help='Input model').

Comment: Looks like you want to put the parameter in the file without any changes. Why does `line = "Model is" + args.modeltype` not work for you?

Comment: But what would the 
if args.modeltype == ??? change to for that to work. That part is what is confusing me, how do I set up the variable so that I am not making it equal itself.

Comment: You don't need that `if` statement at all.

Comment: I do need it because there are some other models in the file that can be run and then I need to edit a bunch of other parameters. -M=TR would be a different model set, hence why I use the if statements.

Comment: Are any of those options actually optional?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but wouldn't something like `str.split` work to split the args (modeltype) and process each model number?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, what do you mean optional? You mean the modeltype argument? There's a whole set of other models that can be run, but a set of models that go by just a number and can be input as a combination.

Comment: Can't you do a `for model in args.modeltype.split()` and then do a check like `if model ==...`?

Comment: I will try that! Thank you. And sorry I read the other part wrong smac89 - the files really aren't optional but I just started with argparse and my main tutorials taught me on how to set up flags. I thought I needed to set up the flags like that. I should change that...they shouldn't be optional lol.

Comment: I don't know what tutorial you are following, but the main docs located here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html are more than enough to clear any confusions, so I suggest you peruse that before you continue with your tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If you replaced your `-M` argument with the following:

```
parser.add_argument('models', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                help='list of models to run')
```

then `args.models` would be a list of the models you specified, as in

```
python my_script.py -g=geneA.phy -t=treefile.phy 0 1 2 3
```

would result in `args.models` being `['0', '1', '2', '3']`, which you can then do whatever you want with (to be honest, your question is not at all clear on what you want done with this information).

Comment: How would I save that input as a variable to use in my if statement?

if args.model == args.model?

For some reason this part is really confusing me.

Comment: Part of the problem is you seem to be treating every possible set of models as a *single* model. I think you just want to check if `args.models` is not empty, then do something like `print("Model is {}".format(" ".join(args.models)))`.

Comment: Yes you're right, I was treating each combo as a model and I shouldn't. Thanks!

Comment: That worked. I still kept my loop because there are other models that can be used (individually) and at the end of the if else statement:

line = 'Model is {}'.format(" ".join(args.model))) and it prints very nicely with any combination for the numbered model set. Thank you!